# How to decode any hard string literal character (\r\n, &amp;, etc,.) for proper formatting display?

Tags: java, html, format

I have some text that is being passed in as a string to my service:

```
"Hello,\r\n\r\nHow are you?\r\n\r\nBest.\r\n\r\nBill &amp; Bob"
```

As you can see there are literals being passed in for carriage return linefeed and the & (there could be others but not sure at this point).

How can I encode those so when displaying in an html page formatting for carriage return and & show up properly?

Can I just replace every literal instance as such?

```
text = text.replace("\\r\\n"),"\n"); 
text = text.replace("&amp;"),"&");
```

or is there a library to do this for me?

(there could also be other markup that comes in as well).

Comment: You need to understand what escaping means.  If you blindly decode every escape sequence you've ever heard of, you will break some strings and create security holes.

Comment: You should pick a single escaping scheme suitable for your protocol, and _nothing else_.

Comment: @SLaks: Thanks! Can you elaborate on "pick a single escaping scheme suitable for your protocol"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html). It should be able to decode most of the HTML escape sequences.

You can find the api doc [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml%28java.lang.String%29).